# Get base derived from

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Suppose I have a class like so:

```
template<class T>
class Base{ };
```

Suppose I have another class like so:

```
template<class T, class Other>
class Derived :
  public virtual Base<T>, 
  public virtual OtherRandomClass<Other> 
{ };
```

Is there some way to create a template class to determine which version of `Base` (if any) a random class like `Derived` is derived from?

Comment: You can simply provide a `typedef` in `Derived`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That is true....but I am lazy and don't want to rewrite a ton of code (all thought that may be my fall back)

Comment: The alternative is to compile a list of all possible `T` types. More work.

Comment: That question doesn't necessarily have a unique answer: What if a class inherits from multiple `Base`s (possibly with different `T`s)?

Comment: @melpomene In my case I **know** that this is impossible because it my "base" returns a `T` somewhere----if another class where to try to inherit from it multiple times (with a different template parameter) there would be an error (I would hope).....but about that in general....maybe I should look for a template function that returns a list, not a single type

Comment: @DarthRubik I added a response that detects those cases when `Derived` inherits only once and extracts the type. For a list of types, I guess it's a bit more work to do. Anyway, that solution gives you a compile time error if you try to use a class that inherits more than once from `Base`. Could it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution (working since C++11 - well, it works with C++14, but it does it with C++11 if you use `Base<T>` instead of `auto` as a return type for `f`):

```
#include<utility>
#include<type_traits>

template<class T>
class Base{ };

template<class T>
class OtherRandomClass{ };

template<class T, class Other>
class Derived :
    public virtual Base<T>, 
    public virtual OtherRandomClass<Other> 
{ };

template<typename T>
constexpr auto f(const Base<T> &b) { return b; }

template<typename T>
struct S {
    using type = decltype(f(std::declval<T>()));
};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename S<Derived<int, double>>::type, Base<int>>::value, "!");
}
```

It doesn't work if `Derived` inherits more than once from `Base`.
Using sfinae (something like the `void_t` idiom) one can even design a class that works similarly to `enable_if`: it has `type` only if `T` actually inherits from `Base` once.
It would have the following form:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto f(const Base<T> &b) { return b; }

template<typename...>
using void_t = void;

template<typename T, typename = void_t<>>
struct S { };

template<typename T>
struct S<T, void_t<decltype(f(std::declval<T>()))>> {
    using type = decltype(f(std::declval<T>()));
};
```

This struct can be used at compile time for any template trickery you can imagine.

In both cases, `S::type` (if it exists) is the type of the base class from which `Derived` inherits, that is `Base<T>`.
See the `static_assert` in the `main` function of the example for further details.

Comment: Cool....This is exactly what I needed!!!!! I hadn't thought to use a function to data mine the type

Comment: @DarthRubik Actually it's quite tricky. I was not sure it would have worked till I tried it!! :-)

Comment: Also gave me a crash course in the weird world of the `void_t` hack

Comment: @DarthRubik `void_t` detection idiom. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

// placeholder template
template<class SomeDerived> struct traits {};

template<class T>
class Base{ };

template<class T>
class OtherRandomClass{ };

template<class T, class Other>
class Derived :
  public virtual Base<T>, 
  public virtual OtherRandomClass<Other> 
{ };


// specialise for our class to provide introspection
template<
  class T1, 
class T2>
struct traits<
  Derived<T1, T2>
  >
{
    using t1_type = T1;
    using first_base_type = Base<T1>;
};

int main()
{
  Derived<int, float> x;

  using mytraits = traits<decltype(x)>;
  std::cout << typeid(mytraits::t1_type).name() << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeid(mytraits::first_base_type).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Wow. So easy, I used such a complex solution instead!! The only drawback is that this works only for `Derived` or, at least, you have to provide a specialization for each class for which you want to detect the base. Not sure it's what the OP asked for. In the comments he mentioned _another class where to try to inherit from it_...

Comment: @skypjack yes you're stuck with having to produce traits for each shape of class (or template) that you wish to introspect. My feeling is that often reaching out for code like this is a result of a design error.

Comment: Sure, I don't want to discuss the why behind a design decision, I'm only trying to answer the OP. Thank you for your reply.